# iOS Widget does not read UserDeafults value for the first time in the home screen

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widget, userdefaults

I set my WidgetView using value of UserDefaults.
To share data between widget and core app, I set appGroup already.

```swift
let appGroupId = "group.com.myAppGroupId"
Text(UserDefaults(suiteName: appGroupId)!.object(forKey: "githubId") as? String ?? "??")
```

It shows well in preview, but when I add it to home screen, it cannot read property. And in same condition, when I rebuild app (cmd+r), widget in the home screen read value of UserDefaults well.

I cannot guess the reason.

+++++ Add more code

Actually, I defined my `githubId` as UserDefaults like this using property wrapper.

```swift
extension UserDefaults {
    enum Key: String {
        case githubId
    }
  
    static let shared: UserDefaults = {
        let appGroupId = "group.com.myAppGroupId"
        return UserDefaults(suiteName: appGroupId)!
    }()

    @UserDefault(key: .githubId)
    static var githubId: String?
}
```

And my property wrapper is seems like this.

```swift
@propertyWrapper
struct UserDefault<Value> {
    let key: String
    let defaultValue: Value
    var container: UserDefaults = .shared
    private let publisher = PassthroughSubject<Value, Never>()
    
    var wrappedValue: Value {
        get {
            return container.object(forKey: key) as? Value ?? defaultValue
        }
        set {
            if let optional = newValue as? AnyOptional, optional.isNil {
                container.removeObject(forKey: key)
            } else {
                container.set(newValue, forKey: key) //this is where I set my value
            }
            publisher.send(newValue)
        }
    }

    var projectedValue: AnyPublisher<Value, Never> {
        return publisher.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

extension UserDefault where Value: ExpressibleByNilLiteral {
    init(key: UserDefaults.Key, _ container: UserDefaults = .shared) {
        self.init(key: key.rawValue, defaultValue: nil, container: container)
    }
}
```

In `LoginViewModel` , I set githubId value.

```swift
class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var githubId = UserDefaults.githubId ?? ""
    private var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        $githubId
            .sink { githubId in
                UserDefaults.githubId = githubId
            }
            .store(in: &subscriptions)
    }
}
```

Finally I use this value in my app, and widget extension using `UserDefaults.githubId`

The code I wrote above ( `UserDefaults(suiteName: appGroupId)!.object(forKey: "githubId")` ) long version of  `UserDefaults.githubId` .

Comment: Can share more code so that we may see where is this value being set and where are you accessing it? It seems for the first time you’re accessing the value before it’s being set in the user defaults.

Comment: @Adeel, I added more detail code.

Comment: `.sink` wont work in a widget. Whatever you want to display in a widget has to be done when you setup the timeline. Widgets aren't listening for changes. You have to reload the widget timelines from the app when there are changes. consider each timeline entry list a screenshot.

Comment: @loremipsum I thought if app changes UserDefaults, widget also can get its value. After I added `WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()` after set `UserDefaults.githubId = githubId`, it works fine!!! Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it worked. I put it in as an answer do you mind accepting and maybe upvoting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.sink` won't work in a widget.

Whatever you want to display in a widget has to be done when you setup the timeline. Widgets aren't listening for changes.

You have to reload the widget timelines from the app when there are changes. consider each timeline entry like a screenshot.

`WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()`

Reloading is metered so make sure you have a check and don't reload excessively.

Answer (score 1):

Is it an option to use @AppStorage ?
Your code could then look like this:

```
@AppStorage('githubId) var id:String
Text(id)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But considering loremipsum's comment above, I think still need to reload the widget timelines even if using AppStorage.